# Cannot reserve memory for tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I got a Java Web-archieve (~150MB) containing a a web-app that I want to customize a bit before deploying on Tomcat. So in eclipse I add an (existing) Tomcat-server with the following start-up-information:

```
-Dcatalina.base="C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.65" 
-Dcatalina.home="C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.65" 
-Dwtp.deploy="C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.65\wtpwebapps" 
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.65\endorsed" 
-Xmx2000m
```

I am working on Win 64bit, so I assumed reserving 2GB for Tomcat should work. However when I want to start that server from within eclipse I get the following error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Could not reserve enough space for 2048000KB object heap

Accoring to Task-Manager I have only 5 of 8GB of RAM currently allocated. Thus allocating two further should work.

Is there any further option that I have to provide to allocate that memory or am I stuck on ~1200MB that obviously do not suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is just as simple as confuding. Obviously I did not have enough free memory on my computer.

Shutting-down some processes handled the issue. After having started Tomcat I could also re-open those processes without any problems, indicating that there was some unreleased memory which is not shown in Task-Manager.